# WAMP - Your port 80 is not actually used

Tags: apache, apache2, wamp, wampserver

I was using wamp server for a long,but suddenly today it stopped working.

When i start wamp the icon doesnt turn to green it stays with orange.

I dont have skype and i have disabled IIS from windows features.but still it doesnt work.

i checked apache error log it shows the following:

[Mon Jan 27 14:07:42.369461 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6220:tid 404] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Mon Jan 27 14:07:42.414463 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6220:tid 404] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37

[Mon Jan 27 14:07:42.414463 2014] [core:notice] [pid 6220:tid 404] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.4\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'

[Mon Jan 27 14:07:42.417464 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6220:tid 404] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6384

[Mon Jan 27 14:07:42.441465 2014] [:crit] [pid 6384] (-2146173818)Unknown error: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator

[Mon Jan 27 14:07:42.443465 2014] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 6220:tid 404] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may sound silly, but check your Windows PATH setting for odd characters.

This has been caused in the past by a corruption of the PATH.

Comment: Like what sort of odd characters?